# Webpack 4 ignores UglifyJsPlugin

Tags: webpack

When adding `minimize: true` to my Webpack config (as said [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimization-minimize)), JavaScript is indeed minified, but when I add it manually, exactly as said [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimization-minimizer), the output is not minified.

```
// This minifies my assets
{
  // ...
  optimization: {minimize: true},
}

// This ignores the minification plugin
{
  // ...
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
  },
}
```

Yes, we are talking about `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin`.

It's as simple as that, but it still doesn't do what it's supposed to. Any idea on how to tackle this issue with Webpack 4.17?

Comment: verify your install , package.json entry and folder under 'node_modules'

Comment: @RobertRowntree and check for what? it's installed. (version 1.3.0)

Comment: Are you setting the `mode` Webpack option to `production`? `minimize` is `false` by default when `mode` is not production. Either that, or specify `minimize: true` in your config.

Comment: I am setting that to `mode: 'none'` becuase I wanted to have full control. AFAIK, `minimize: true` is equivalent of `minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()]`. Hence, I am trying to pass `minimizer: [...]` so I get full control. Is there anything I didn't get quite right?

Comment: I think you also need to set `minimize: true` just to get that out of the way. Confirmed with Webpack source code, added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `mode: none` in Webpack, you also need to specify `minimize: true` yourself, for the `minimizer` to work, as per [the Webpack source code](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/9f0056b10d6997fd8e1472fec4b8c84b5d6b1db7/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js#L451-L455):

```
    if (options.optimization.minimize) {
        for (const minimizer of options.optimization.minimizer) {
            minimizer.apply(compiler);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like I got confused by the *override* keyword in the docs. Thanks!